# Web proxy to rewrite outbound URLs?

Tags: http-proxy, privoxy

I use Privoxy on my Windows host to filter incoming web pages, but I now need to perform a URL rewrite on outgoing queries as well.

I asked in the mailing list but no reply so far, so I wanted to check here whether Privoxy supports rewriting outbound queries, or if I need to move to another web proxy available for Windows.

Thank you.

Comment: you say you asked on the "mailing list".. i think it has one, but while it possibly has some connection to the privoxy sourceforge support tracker thing, but  may be the privoxy sourceforge support tracker thing is the privoxy place to ask. From my experience things get replied to and answered there.   http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=11118&atid=211118  it could be you asked on what might be a regular user mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I went through gmane.comp.web.privoxy.user, but maybe it didn't make it to the actual mailing list.

Comment: it probably did make it to the mailing list but the privoxy sourceforge support tracker is the place rather than that. also possible the tracker sends to both it and that. have a look based on your q on the tracker and report back, like if it also went to the mailing list, and the answer so it's here. It's an interesting question